# Date Time Conversion Error

Tags: c#, datetime

In a string variable I have date in following format : `Tue Jul 23 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013`

I tried to convert it into a datetime variable , and got invalid date time error.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(t);
```

How can I convert into a `DateTime` format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` and use custom format string:

```
var input = "Tue Jul 23 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013";
var format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTCzzz yyyy";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: _Hmm_, but Marcin this prints 22 July?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, but that's probably because of your local timezone (which is not +530, is it?). `DateTime` and timezones is a still a bit confusing topic for me, but I would say that's the reason.

Comment: Yeah, mine is _UTC+2_ so that could be the reason. _DateTime and timezones is a still a bit confusing topic for me_ Me neither but [I think this is good for us :)](https://twitter.com/joshsusser/status/257725572275376128)

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Well now I have chrome returning an all new avatar. I should rather look for a common solution!! @SonerGönül perfect status :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
string[] formats= { "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTCzzz yyyy" }
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Jul 23 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013", formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```